# tkinter child window opens two windows?

Tags: python, tkinter

When I open a child window with Tkinter using Toplevel(), two windows open instead of just one. This is my code:

```
import os
import sys
from Tkinter import *
import tkFileDialog
from pdfConverter import *

#Some important parameters
docDir = '/Users/Person/Python/12_PythonPackages/01_PyDocSearch/Library'

currFilePath = os.getcwd()
fileList = []
allPossibleFiles = os.listdir(docDir)
for file in allPossibleFiles:
    if '.pdf' in file or '.doc' in file:
        fileList.append(file)

def startSearch():
    filePath = input_dir.get()
    findText = textToSearch.get()
    status.set("Searching now")


    def buildIndex():
        try:
            fileName = fileList.pop()
            statusStr = "Status: Working on file: " + str(fileName)
            print statusStr
            status.set(statusStr)
            if '.pdf' in fileName:
                doc = convert_pdf(docDir + '/' + fileName)
                #doc = convert_pdf(docDir + '/' + fileName)
                if findText in doc:
                    foundSpot = doc.find(findText)
                    print doc[foundSpot-100:foundSpot+100]
                else:
                    print 'Text not found'
            #doc.close()
            #infile = open(filePath + '/' + fileName,'r')
            #infile.close()
        except IndexError:
            statusStr = "Status: Done! You can press 'Quit' now"
            print statusStr
            status.set(statusStr)
            return
        #root.after(100,fixFiles)
    root.after(10,buildIndex)

def input_file():
    #Get the input directory.
    directory1 = tkFileDialog.askdirectory(mustexist=True)
    input_dir.set(directory1)

def output_file():
    #Get the input directory.
    directory2 = tkFileDialog.askdirectory(mustexist=True)
    output_dir.set(directory2)

class App:
    def __init__(self, master):

        l = []
        l.append(Label(master, text=""))
        l.append(Label(master, text=" Program: PyDocSearcher"))
        l.append(Label(master, text=" Version: 0.1"))
        l.append(Label(master, text=""))
        l.append(Label(master, text=""))
        for i in range(len(l)):
            l[i].grid(row = i, columnspan = 4, sticky = W)

        i += 1
        inputrow = []
        inputrow.append(Label(master, text="Enter directory to search:"))
        inputrow.append(Entry(root, width = 40, textvariable=input_dir))
        inputrow.append(Button(root, text='Browse', command=input_file))
        i += 1
        for j in range(len(inputrow)):
            inputrow[j].grid(row = i, column=j, sticky = W)

        i += 1
        inputrow = []
        inputrow.append(Label(master, text="Search for text:"))
        inputrow.append(Entry(root, width = 40, textvariable=textToSearch))
        i += 1
        for j in range(len(inputrow)):
            inputrow[j].grid(row = i, column=j, sticky = W)

        i += 1
        spacer = Label(master, text="")
        spacer.grid(row = i)

        i += 1
        status.set("Status: Enter your selections and press 'Fix Files!'")
        statuslabel = Label(master, textvariable=status, relief = RIDGE, width = 80, pady = 5, anchor=W)
        bFixFiles = Button(root, text='Search!', command = startSearch)
        bQuit = Button(root, text='Quit', command = root.destroy)

        statuslabel.grid(row=i, column = 0, columnspan = 2)
        bFixFiles.grid(row=i, column=2, sticky=E)
        bQuit.grid(row=i, column=3, sticky=W)

        top = Toplevel()
        top.title("About this application...")

        msg = Message(top, text="about_message")
        button = Button(top, text="Dismiss", command=top.destroy)

        button.pack()
        msg.pack()



root = Tk()
root.title("PyDocSearcher")
input_dir = StringVar()
textToSearch = StringVar()
status = StringVar()
choice = IntVar()
app = App(root)

# start Tkinter
root.mainloop()
```

The above code gives me TWO child windows in addition to the main. One of the child windows looks fine with the button and the message. The other one is just a small blank window with the title 'tk'.

Now, if I reduce my code to the bare minimum, it seems to work fine. I just get the main window and the one child window that I want:

```
from Tkinter import *
import tkFileDialog

class App:
    def __init__(self, master):
        inputrow = Label(master, text="This is some text")
        inputrow.grid(row=1)
        bQuit = Button(root, text='Quit', command = root.destroy)
        bQuit.grid(row=2, column=3, sticky=W)

        top = Toplevel()
        top.title("About this application...")

        msg = Message(top, text="about_message")
        button = Button(top, text="Dismiss", command=top.destroy)
        button.pack()
        msg.pack()

root = Tk()
root.title("Test Title")
app = App(root)
# start Tkinter
root.mainloop()
```

Any ideas as to why I might be getting that extra child window? I can't figure out what might be causing that extra window to pop up.

Comment: Your script open only two windows here. Are you sure the third one is not something related to XWindow (and is specific to Mac OX)? Can you tell what is in the extra window?

Comment: Yeah, I have no idea. All I know is the code I posted at the top gives me 3 windows and the stripped down code I posted below only gives two windows. The code for the child window is identical. As I mentioned, the extra window is blank with a title 'tk'.

Comment: I use Linux and I do not have empty Tk windows with either of your scripts. My guess is, Tk window appears once for all tk scripts. If I am right, you will get it with your second script too if it is run first after Tk and Xwindow runtimes are terminated.

Answer (score 0):

I ran the first block of code on my mac and I did *not* get three windows as you describe. I see only two. Since I had to comment out the import of pdfConverter to get it to work, maybe that's the culprit? Try adding that import to your minimized version and see if you get the extra window. Perhaps pdfConverter is creating a window for you.

Comment: Weird... I commented out the pdfConverter and I still get the three windows. I will have to try this code on my windows and linux computers at work next week to see if I still get this problem. So far I have only tested this at home.